# Não retorna valor pro javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um problema que o valor que vem do meu controller não volta pro javascript.

Vou explicar o que acontece:

Eu envio requisições via ajax para o meu controller e ele fica aguardando o retorno de valores, enquanto não estiver nenhum valor de retorno o meu ajax fica aguardando, aí quando tem o valor de retorno ele exibe na minha modal, até então se eu estiver na página que eu abrir a modal funciona legal sem nenhum problema, mas se eu der um refresh na tela (F5) ou então mudar da página (view) o valor que fica aguardando no controller não chega mas no ajax. Mas no controller ele processa toda a informação como é para ser exibida na modal.

---

## ajax

```js
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: urlW,
        success: function (data) {

}
```

## controller

```cs
AnalistaBean a = new AnalistaBean();
a = atendeBussines.ReceiveCTI((Socket)Session["ConexaoCTI"]);
return Json(new { r = a });
```

Mas ele só para de mandar a requisição pro ajax quando eu do o F5 ou mudo de página

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54251/discussion-on-question-by-user3703309-nao-retorna-valor-pro-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Basta você adicionar um campo hidden na sua view que recebe o valor da sua requisição vindo do controle e ele ficará persistido.
Para pegar e enviar de novo a requisição é só você pegar com javascript o `value` desse input.